# Windows 7 Start Menu All Programs - display all folders, not just a single scrollable column

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

In Windows 95/XP/Vista I could click on the start menu, "All Programs", and I would get a list of all my programs.

In Windows 7 when I click start menu, "All Programs", I get a single column with a scroll bar - but that's not what I want, I want to see All Programs.

How do I do this? I've looked in the start menu options but cannot find an option that appears to show me all my programs.

Answer (score 2):

I've got used to typing WinKey and then the program name.  The old style Start Menu got too unwieldy once you have a lot of program installed, and sorting them into folders was too much hassle.

Anyway, I saw someone link to to [**Classic Shell**](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/) recently, which is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I only just noticed how old this question is.

Comment: Question still remains. I guess that's just like Microsoft: take something that _was_ useful and %$#@ it up. This is what we get for paying for software. That, and any developer with _any_ skill or sense of propriety would _never_ work for Microsoft.

Comment: I've found the winkey+type to work better than the old system.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the scrollable start menu is just the way it is windows 7, there's no simple way around it.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no simple way around it either, hence the question!